# nodejs - JSON.stringify Error object

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to convert `Error object` to JSON. However, the `Error message` seems to be lost.

```
try{
    require('someModule');
}catch(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) //{"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"}
}
```

Did I do anything wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not the error message being lost. What you just put in the comment is the full error object.

Comment: Where is the error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue has to do with the fact that some of the properties set on Errors are configured as non-enumerable.

Here's something you can use to properly stringify Error objects, it sets a `toJSON()` method that `JSON.stringify()` looks for when converting an object:

```
var config = {
  configurable: true,
  value: function() {
    var alt = {};
    var storeKey = function(key) {
      alt[key] = this[key];
    };
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach(storeKey, this);
    return alt;
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'toJSON', config);
```

Then just use `JSON.stringify()` as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. By the way, is `var storeKey = function(key)` a typo?

Comment: @user3828771 Code is fixed now.

Comment: It's important to note that this breaks mongodb client: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-554